# Server RMI stop automatically when I start it

Tags: java, rmi

I'm frensh so sorry for my english.

I'm trying to start a server rmi but the application stop whitout error :

Here my code:

public class Server {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {



        RemoteFunction  skeleton = (RemoteFunction) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(new FunctionImpl(), 0); 

        int port = Integer.parseInt(Jndiprop.getString("port"));

        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);


        registry.rebind(Jndiprop.getString("url"), skeleton); 

        System.out.println("Rmi start");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}
```

}

the port and the url are ok.

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You must store the Registry in a static variable. Otherwise it can be garbage-collected, which leads to a train of events that allows the whole JVM to exit.